# How to add columns to DataFrame in groupby

Tags: python, pandas

This is my DataFrame:

```
client_uuid supplier_uuid order_uuid
1           a             1
1           b             2
2           a             3
1           a             4
2           b             5
2           a             6
```

My goal is to add 2 columns to the DataFrame:

- Order Number: The number of orders that this client has made up to this point
- Repeat order: If this order is to any supplier that the client has purchased from in the past

My desired results

```
client_uuid supplier_uuid order_uuid order_n is_repeat
1           a             1          1       f
1           b             2          2       f  
2           a             3          1       f
1           a             4          3       t
2           b             5          2       f
2           a             6          3       t
```

I have some basic pseudo code:

```
def set_new_columns(client_df):
  for row in client_df:
      increment order count for client
      check if this order is to a supplier the client has been to before
      set the new columns to the row

df.groupby("client_uuid").apply(set_new_columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for the first part of your question.

```
df['order_n'] = (df
                 .groupby('client_uuid')
                 .order_uuid
                 .transform(lambda group: group.notnull().cumsum()))
```

And this should answer the second part:

```
df['first_order'] = (df
                     .groupby(['client_uuid', 'supplier_uuid'])
                     .order_uuid
                     .transform('first'))
df['is_repeat'] = df.order_uuid != df.first_order

>>> df
   client_uuid supplier_uuid  order_uuid  first_order  order_n is_repeat
0            1             a           1            1        1     False
1            1             b           2            2        2     False
2            2             a           3            3        1     False
3            1             a           4            1        3      True
4            2             b           5            5        2     False
5            2             a           6            3        3      True
```